# Pulling data from 6 5TB hard drives in Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas

The raid controller in the NAS enclosure failed, but the drives are still operational. I do know it is setup in a RAID configuration, which configuration, I am not sure, as I didn't set it up. Safe guess is RAID 5, correct? Is there a way to figure out how they were configured? The enclosure most likely can't be replaced due to lack of availability. I was instructed by the hard drive & NAS company (Seagate) to load up Ubuntu and recover the data. Sounds easy...So is it really easy as loading Ubuntu, connecting all 6 drives with sata cables and a 7th drive to copy the needed data to, from the array? Will Ubuntu just simply read the array or do I need to learn how to code? :P

I appreciate any help!

Comment: How are we to know, you didn't even tell us the model of the NAS enclosure though that would limit your audience capable of responding.  I would mount a single drive (read-only) and explore what is there looking for clues.  What `fs` is used as most NAS devices I've looked at are built on GNU/Linux, but vary somewhat (even same make, over time). I would then likely compare the one drive with the others (ie. mounting them and looking). No, coding isn't required no (you can use tools already in Ubuntu).

Comment: After setting up Ubuntu you will probably need `mdadm` installed to see the array if there was one on the drives and if it was software controlled.

Comment: As far as I know Seagate only made one 6 bay NAS enclosure which is the "NAS Pro" (not very pro) :D and in my case it is the 30TB enclosure. Part Number is 1JL5P6-500. This should be a Linux based platform. Thanks for the insightful advice thus far!

Comment: Are you sure the RAID controller failed? If so, what are the chances of finding a replacement board? I don't think that you'll be able to get data off of 6 RAID drives singly. You might check for firmware updates at https://www.seagate.com/support/network-attached-storage/business-storage/seagate-nas-pro/